# C# Filtering DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter

Dear Stackoverflow users,

Let me first off say that I am not very well known with C# at all so if I might say or do something doubtful, then you why.

I have this DataGridView filled with a lot of rows. Now I am thinking about making a function so the users can filter the rows. To filter the rows I use this line and it works!:

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("company= '{0}'", cbCompanyFilter.Text);
```

But as you can see I only use one argument to filter the rows. I was wondering if there is a way of filtering the rows using multiple arguments in one line.

I tried to do it like this:

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("bedrijf = '{0}'", cbCompanyFilter.Text);
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("afdruklocatie = '{0}'", cbPrintFilter.Text);
```

But this doesn't work properly.

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with this matter.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AND` operator like this: 
`string.Format("bedrijf = '{0}' AND afdruklocatie = '{1}'", cbCompanyFilter.Text , cbPrintFilter.Text)`